# regex capturing all content instead of just untill first defined string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am converting the content of some tutorials and extracting the `html` tags.
I made this regex: `/<html\>(?!html)([\s\S]*)<\/html\>/` trying to make it capture just the content of the first HTML group, but it captures everything untill the last html, despite my (maybe bad placed) negative lookahead.

What did I miss here? ([live example](http://regex101.com/r/lQ3zY6/1))

```
This is text
<html>
  <div>
    some content
  </div>
</html>

This is more text
<html>
  <div>
    some content
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make the regex lazy:

```
<html\>([\s\S]*?)<\/html\>
```

That should take everything up until the first html tag.

Comment: Aha... ok, so I was that near and still didn't see that. Thank you!

Comment: @Rikard the placement of `(?!html)` is useless.It does not do anything.It should be `((?!html).)*`.

Comment: @pritaeas could you edit the answer to make everyone happy. Maybe just remove the `(?!html)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>(?:(?!<\/html>).)*<\/html\>
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lQ3zY6/2